# Get String From CodeBehind

Tags: c#, asp.net

What is the difference between `<%#...%> and <%=...%>` ? For example I wanted to take the username of the logged in user and I tried with `"<%# Membership.GetUser().UserName %>"` but this didn't work. Then I tried with `<%= Membership.GetUser().UserName %>` and with this works. Why with the first try (`"<%# Membership.GetUser().UserName %>"`) didn't work but the second works fine (`<%= Membership.GetUser().UserName %>`) ?

With this code didn't work I can't get the field from "`Membership.GetUser().UserName`":

```
<div id="profileHeader">
    <h1><%# Membership.GetUser().UserName %></h1>
</div>
```

With this code work I can get the field from "`Membership.GetUser().UserName`":

```
<div id="profileHeader">
    <h1><%= Membership.GetUser().UserName %></h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**<% %>**: standard code-block

**<%# %>**: these servertags are for data-binding expressions.

**<%= %>**: those are for displaying variables.

Answer (score 2):

Abbas is correct, here is the official wiki on the subject

[Code render blocks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6xeyd4z%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), [Data binding expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bda9bbfx%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and [Web Forms syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fy30at8h%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) in general.